# TextView with gestureDetector, onClickListener and onLongClickListener

Tags: android, gestures

I would like to implement a textview with gesture detector, onClickListener and onLongClickListener. Do you think it is possible?

The objective is to get a clickable (normal and long) textview with the option to rotate and scale it using two-finger gesture.

With the next code is possible to perform click, rotate (with bugs, but event works) and scale the textview. The click action is done when the first finger is "UP" and there was any other finger "DOWN".

***The question is:*** how can I get click, longclick and touchable TextView? The next code has click and touchable TextView but no longclick...

Any suggestion?

***Thank you!***

This is my (shrinked) current code:
Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    [...]
    messageTextView = (TouchableTextView) findViewById(R.id.messageView);

    messageTextView.setOnClickListener(this);
    messageTextView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    [...]
}
```

TouchableTextView which extends TextView

```
public class TouchableTextView extends TextView implements View.OnTouchListener,RotationGestureDetector.OnRotationGestureListener {

    private RotationGestureDetector mRotationDetector;
    [Constructors]

    // Called from each constructor
    private void Init(Context context){
        this.setOnTouchListener(this);
        mRotationDetector = new RotationGestureDetector(this,this);
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener l) {
        mRotationDetector.setOnClickListener(l);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (mRotationDetector.onTouchEvent(event))
            return true;

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void OnRotation(RotationGestureDetector rotationDetector) {
        float angle = rotationDetector.getAngle();
        float scale = rotationDetector.getScaleFactor();

        this.setRotation(Math.abs(angle));

        float textSize = Math.min(Math.max(this.getTextSize()*scale, 8f), 50f);
        this.setTextSize(textSize);
    }
}
```

Gesture detector:

```
public class RotationGestureDetector {
    private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;
    private float fX, fY, sX, sY;
    private int ptrID1, ptrID2;
    private float mAngle;
    private float mScale;
    private boolean secondPointer;


    private View mView;

    private OnRotationGestureListener mListener;
private View.OnClickListener mClickListener;

public void setOnClickListener( View.OnClickListener l)
{
    mClickListener = l;
}

public float getAngle() {
    return mAngle;
}

public float getScaleFactor() {
    return mScale;
}

public RotationGestureDetector(OnRotationGestureListener listener, View view){
    mListener = listener;
    mView = view;

    ptrID1 = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
    ptrID2 = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            ptrID1 = event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex());
            secondPointer = false;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            ptrID2 = event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex());
            sX = event.getX(event.findPointerIndex(ptrID1));
            sY = event.getY(event.findPointerIndex(ptrID1));
            fX = event.getX(event.findPointerIndex(ptrID2));
            fY = event.getY(event.findPointerIndex(ptrID2));
            secondPointer = true;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if(ptrID1 != INVALID_POINTER_ID && ptrID2 != INVALID_POINTER_ID){
                float nfX, nfY, nsX, nsY;
                nsX = event.getX(event.findPointerIndex(ptrID1));
                nsY = event.getY(event.findPointerIndex(ptrID1));
                nfX = event.getX(event.findPointerIndex(ptrID2));
                nfY = event.getY(event.findPointerIndex(ptrID2));

                mAngle = angleBetweenPoints(nfX, nfY, nsX, nsY);
                mScale = scaleBetweenLines(fX, fY, sX, sY, nfX, nfY, nsX, nsY);

                if (mListener != null) {
                    mListener.OnRotation(this);
                }
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            ptrID1 = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            if( !secondPointer && mClickListener != null)
                mClickListener.onClick(mView);

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            ptrID2 = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private float angleBetweenPoints (float nfX, float nfY, float nsX, float nsY)
{
    float xDiff = nsX - nfX;
    float yDiff = nsY - nfY;

    return (float)Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(yDiff, xDiff));
}

private float scaleBetweenLines (float fX, float fY, float sX, float sY, float nfX, float nfY, float nsX, float nsY)
{
    float distance1 = (float)Math.sqrt((fX-sX)*(fX-sX) + (fY-sY)*(fY-sY));
    float distance2 = (float)Math.sqrt((nfX-nsX)*(nfX-nsX) + (nfY-nsY)*(nfY-nsY));
    return distance2 / distance1;
}
public static interface OnRotationGestureListener {
    public void OnRotation(RotationGestureDetector rotationDetector);
}
}
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work as expected?

Comment: The problem I want to solve is how to get click,long click and touchable textview.

Comment: please, update the question with that information and detailed explanation of what exactly doesn't work (looks like touch able and click are working based on the question).